# vertical-align doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css

I'm reading a book about css and this confused me. I want to center a text vertically, here's my code:

```css
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#mySpan {
    background-color: red;
}

/* this works fine but when I type the code I first tried */
#mySpan {
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <img src="zemin.jpg" alt="Zemin">
    <span id="mySpan">Align Vertically</span>
</p>
```

This doesn't work. Can you explain this? Why does setting `align` to another element works but setting it to an element directly doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property is all about aligning images (inline blocks) in a text. It determines how the element is positioned within the text flow. Aligning text within the text flow doesn't make much sense, since it *is* the text flow.

See also [vertical-align](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

You can apply the vertical alignment to the span if you make it `inline-block`, but I doubt if that's the behavior you like. Some examples can be found below:

```css
p {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.mySpan {
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
.mySpan.top {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 3em;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#mySpan {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <img src="zemin.jpg" alt="Zemin">Normal text flow. <span class="mySpan">Align middle</span>. <span class="mySpan top">Align top.</span>Continuation of normal text flow
</p>
```